# Flexbox within a flexbox - is it possible?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve the following layout:

```
+---------+---------------------+
|legend   |                     |
+---------+                     |
|csv_input|        map          |
|         |                     |
|         |                     |
|         |                     |
+---------+---------------------+

+---------+-------+
|legend   |       |
+---------+  map  |
|csv_input|       |
|         |       |
+---------+-------+
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zwjm16p3/1/

With this HTML and CSS:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body,
div#wrapper,
div#map {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: #fef;
}
#map {
  flex: 1;
  background: #ffe;
}
#sidebar {
  order: -1;
  flex: 0 0 20em;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eff;
}
#sidebar_wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eef;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#legend {
  width: 100%;
  background: #efe;
  flex: 2em 0 0 0;
}
#csv_input {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eef;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebar_wrapper">
      <div id="legend">
        Paste CSV data below.
      </div>
      <textarea id="csv_input"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I see is:

```
+----+----+---------------------+
|lege|csv_|                     |
|    |    |                     |
|    |    |        map          |
|    |    |                     |
|    |    |                     |
|    |    |                     |
+----+----+---------------------+
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is `flex-direction: row;` being ignored?
2. Do I need the `#sidebar_wrapper` div, or can a div both be the child in one flexbox and the container of another?

Comment: You might want to set `flex-direction: column;` to `#sidebar_wrapper` in order to get the desired layout. fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zwjm16p3/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap the whole div's in one flex box with `flex-direction:row` and the inner two div's with `flex-direction : column`

```
#wrapper{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:row;
}
#sidebar{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

here is the working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zwjm16p3/4/) for your problem

Comment: Thanks that fixes the flexbox direction but not the height of the text area https://jsfiddle.net/zwjm16p3/6/  The textarea does not occupy the remaining height of the column.

Comment: @chrisdew - You are missing `display: flex` on the sidebar. [Example with sidebar display flex](https://jsfiddle.net/hgwvvkew/)

Comment: @chrisdew - Also, if you want to take up the entire viewport, you may not need to have the wrapper and just use the body as the main flex container... [like this example](https://jsfiddle.net/kg0nce9a/).